# What is the equivalent of npm run start:ci in yarn?

Tags: vue.js, npm, bitbucket, cypress, yarnpkg

I'm trying to configure Bitbucket CI/CD for cypress testing on my vue app which uses yarn for package management.

Is there any way to start server in background by yarn?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`yarn start` command is equivalent to `npm run start`
However if you have created a custom command in your package.json for `start:ci` you can use equivalent yarn command as `yarn start:ci`

You can also use `yarn run start:ci` however its `run` is redundent here. Please see this documentation
https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/run/